# SharePoint 2013 RESTful calls returning 404 not found

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, rest

Using the [Get started with the SharePoint 2013 REST service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142380.aspx), I am trying to access the following internal SharePoint site:
http://mycs.nce.dirc.aon/sites/SuperSecret/default.aspx

I have tried sending a GET request to the following URLs:

http://mycs.nce.dirc.aon/sites/SuperSecret/_api/SuperSecret

http://mycs.nce.dirc.aon/sites/SuperSecret/_api/web

http://mycs.nce.dirc.aon/SuperSecret/_api/SuperSecret

http://mycs.nce.dirc.aon/SuperSecret/_api/web

Everytime the server responds with a 404, this leads me to believe I am crafting the URL wrong.  Can someone take a look at the URL and recommend what the correct version might be.

Authentication wise, I need to login, so what I was doing was logging in normally and then using that session and manually crafting the GET with a Chrome plugin.

Note:  I have not "enabled" any type REST feature since I was not the one who originally set it up, so this might also be the case if the feature needs to be enabled.

BTW: This is also posted here, but this stack looked more relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298197/sharepoint-2013-restful-calls-returning-404-not-found

Answer (score 2):

I would check out the fiddler. That is the normal response SharePoint will return for it's REST interfaces. I know one thing if you are using windows authentication with your SharePoint instance that it does a Negotiate NTLM call before serving you the request. You need to have a valid NTLM session going before making any calls to the webservice. Get Fiddler and see what is happening before you get the 404 response

Answer (score 1):

The correct one is `http://mycs.nce.dirc.aon/sites/SuperSecret/_api/web`. If you type this url in a browser like Chrome, it should display the current site information in xml.

Also check your protocol, it might be https instead of http.